# How to formulate the correct question?

Tags: grammar, questions

I'm building a chart on a report and I need to create a question for its title.

The chart shows return on capital employed, so I'm thinking about a title like:

> What's our return on capital employed?

Or:

> How well is our capital employed being remunerated?

Are these correct? I can't find a better one...

Thanks for helping!

Comment: **"Graph on investment return"** or **"Involved capital return chart"**

Comment: Ok, but I want the title as a question.

Comment: **What is the investment return?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first suggestion,

> **What's our return on capital employed?**

looks pretty good. It's short, snappy, and understandable. The second one is grammatically correct, but rather clunky and needs more time to understand.

Answer (score 1):

What's our return on capital (ROC)? or What's our return on invested capital (ROIC)?

This is known as a Financial Ratio.

[ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_capital)

Return on capital (ROC), or return on invested capital (ROIC), is a ratio used in finance, valuation and accounting, as a measure of the profitability and value-creating potential of companies after taking into account the amount of initial capital invested.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_capital) The ratio is calculated by dividing the after-tax operating income (NOPAT) by the book value of both debt and equity capital less cash/equivalents.

Note: employed is a no-go.